# Session states in ajax callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Someone told me `Session` or `HttpContext.Current.User` will return different value when we are working with ajax postback, in case of when the are so many user are live to site.

For example, suppose there are 1000 people are online in site, and from them 100 call ajax method/ wenmethod and on this we might get different value of `Session` or `HttpContext.Current.User` as per every user's `Session` or `HttpContext.Current.User` value are different.

But my concept says it will return specific person's (who requested) `Session` or `HttpContext.Current.User` value, and server will be clear whose value need to be return.

What you all guys says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session ID is stored in a cookie (or in the query string if so configured). It's unique per browser session.

> ASP.NET provides session-state management to enable you to store information associated with a unique browser session across multiple requests.

For each request, the session ID cookie is referenced and the session for that unique ID is populated.

Additional information can be found on the [HttpSessionState Class Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the Remarks section.